# how to create a infinite scrolling animation in action script3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

im creating a fish tank..so what i want to do is my fish should be  infinite scrolling..i'm using action script 3..this is the code i used..but it's not working..

```
var scrollSpeed:uint = 5;

//This adds two instances of the movie clip onto the stage.



//This positions the second movieclip next to the first one.
f1.x = 0;
f2.x = f1.width;

//Adds an event listener to the stage.
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveScroll); 

//This function moves both the images to left. If the first and second 
//images goes pass the left stage boundary then it gets moved to 
//the other side of the stage. 
function moveScroll(e:Event):void{
f1.x -= scrollSpeed;  
f2.x -= scrollSpeed;  

if(f1.x < +f1.width){
f1.x = f1.width;
}else if(f2.x < +f2.width){
f2.x = f2.width;
}
}
```

**f1 and f2 is my fish instance name**

Comment: I'm a little confused, are you looking to move you fish to the opposite side of the screen after they go off one side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lines are at the bottom.

```
if (f1.x < f1.width) {
    f1.x = stage.stageWidth - f1.width // f1.width;
} // Removed else

if (f2.x < f2.width) {
    f2.x = f1.width;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this assumes your images/mc's are large enough for the screen, and are duplicates (have the same content)

```
function moveScroll(e:Event):void {
    //position fish 1
    f1.x -= scrollSpeed;
    //when fish 1 is out of bounds (off the screen on the left, set it back to 0
    if (f1.x < -f1.width) {
       f1.x = 0;
    }
    //always position fish2 next to fish 1
    f2.x = f1.x + f1.width;
}
```

another way would be to put them in a array and switch them around, if they dont have the same content:

```
//add fishes to array
var images:Array = new Array();
images.push(f1, f2);

function moveScroll(e:Event):void {
    //position fish 1
    images[0].x -= scrollSpeed;
    //when first fish is out of bounds, remove it from the array (unshift) and add it at the end (push)
    if (images[0].x < -images[0].width) {
       images.push(images.unshift())
    }
    //always position fish2 next to fish 1
    images[1].x = images[0].x + images[0].width;
}
```

these are just basic examples, but you get the idea